# How does one write an add function for a min heap?

Tags: java, heap, min, min-heap

I'm trying to write an add function for a min heap in Java but I can't seem to write one that works properly. I have already tried two solutions for the add method but neither seem to work. I've tried using an int to store the previous position and then reinsert it into the heap but that doesn't produce any results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class ClsPQHeap {
    private int back;
    private int heap[];

public ClsPQHeap (int amount){
    heap = new int[amount];
    back = 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (back == 0){
      return true;  
    } else {
      return false;  
    }
}
public boolean isFull(){
    if (heap.length == back){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
// this is the method that needs help 
public void add(int x){
    if (isEmpty()) {
        heap[back] = x;
    } else if (isFull()){
      System.out.println("Did not add " + x + " array is full");
   } else {
        heap[back + 1] = x;
        for (int i = heap.length; i <= back; i--){
            if (heap[i] > heap[i-1]){
                int temp = heap[i];
                heap[i] = heap[i-1];
                heap[i-1] = temp;
            } else if (heap[i] < heap[i -1]){
                int temp = heap[i];
            }
        }
        /*do {
            if (heap[back] > heap[back+1]){
                int temp = heap[back];
                heap[back] = heap[back + 1];
                heap[back + 1] = temp;
            } else if (heap[back] < heap[back+1]){
            
            }
        } while (heap[0] > heap[back]); */
        back += 1;    
    } 
}
public void print(){
  int count = 1;
  for(int i = 0; i<back; i++){
     System.out.println(count + "." + heap[i]);
     count += 1;
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int myArray[] = {15, 5, 8, 4, 9, 22, 17, 2, 14, 1};
    ClsPQHeap heap = new ClsPQHeap(myArray.length);
    for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        heap.add(myArray[i]);
        heap.print();
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

I've made a little bit of progress since I posted this to the add function. I can now get some of it to print but the values aren't being printed properly or added properly. This is where I'm currently at:

```
public void add(int x){
    back = back+1;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        heap[back] = x;
    } else if (isFull()){
      System.out.println("Did not add " + x + " array is full");
      back = back-1;
   } 
    heap[back + 1] = x;
    for (int i = 1; i<= back+1; i++){
        if (heap[i-1] <= heap[(i-1)/2]){
            int holder;
            holder = heap[i-1];
            heap[i-1] = heap[(i-1)/2];
            heap[(i-1)/2] = holder; 
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- The `for` condition is wrong in the first version: as you *decrease* `i`, the condition should be against a minimum-limit, like `i >= 0`. In the second version, it is an incrementing loop, which solves the issue, except that the algorithm for insertion really needs a decrementing loop -- representing a walk from the bottom of the tree, towards to root.
- In the first version you do not increment `back` when the list is empty. This is solved in the second version. However, in the second version you don't populate the entry at index 0.
- In the first version, the relationship between child and parent node is not calculated in terms of indices. This is somewhat better covered in the second version -- using division by 2 -- but it is still not entirely correct.

Here is how it could be done. Note that there is no need to treat an empty list differently. Also, there is no need to *swap* in each iteration. Just shift values down, leaving a gap for the value `x`, but only assign value `x` when the *right* target index has been identified. This saves some unnecessary assignments along the way.

```
    public void add(int x){
        if (isFull()){
            System.out.println("Did not add " + x + " array is full");
        } else {
            int child = back;
            int parent = (child - 1) / 2;
            while (child > 0 && heap[parent] > x) {
                heap[child] = heap[parent];
                child = parent;
                parent = (child - 1) / 2;
            }
            heap[child] = x;
            back++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Megan, your proposal for edit is not correct. However, could you leave some feedback? Did this answer your question?